# How to limit the downloading speed as slow as getting 20 urls per minute for the scrapy?

Tags: performance, scrapy, delay

Here is my scrapy struture,to ommit concret statements,to keep the main structure visible, to save it as test.py.

```
import scrapy,urllib.request

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 3
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 6

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_SPIDER = 1
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 100000
CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT = 36000
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
RETRY_ENABLED = False
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 1
COOKIES_ENABLED = False

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["some web"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.timeout = 10

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)     

    def parse(self, response):
        do something
```

The info abstract on my console when running it with command `scrapy runspider test.py`.

```
 'downloader/request_count': 3391,
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 25, 12, 29, 43, 101017),
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 25, 12, 24, 10, 63516)}
```

total time = 29min-24min+(43-10)=5min33second=333 seconds
total request =3391
We draw the conclusion that it can run  as quickly as getting 10 urls per second.

Why `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3`,and `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True`,`AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 3` and `AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 6` can't slow down the speed?

How to limit the downloading speed as slow as getting 20 urls per minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing redundant settings (for example `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_SPIDER` is already deprecated) try this spider, it's upper bounded to 20 requests per minute:

```
import scrapy
from datetime import datetime


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': False,
        'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': False
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.debug('%s', datetime.utcnow())
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```